# Custom view with nib as subview doesn't seem to be loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, view, nib

I've created a custom view that loads its content from a nib, like this:

```
/* PricingDataView.h */

#import <UIKit/UIKIt.h>

@interface PricingDataView : UIView {
  UIView *contentView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
@end

/* PricingDataView.m */

#import "PricingDataView.h"

@implementation PricingDataView
@synthesize contentView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PricingDataView" owner:self options:nil];
    [contentView setFrame:frame];
    [self addSubview:contentView];
  }
  return self;
}

/* ... */
```

In the nib file I set `PricingDataView` as the type of the File's Owner， and connected the `contentView` outlet in IB.  I placed a regular `UIView` from the Interface Library onto the full-sized view shown to the user, and then changed it's class name to `PricingDataView`.  It all builds, but at runtime, nothing is rendered where my custom view is supposed to be.

I put breakpoints in `PricingDataView.initWithFrame`, but they don't hit, so I know I'm missing something that would cause the view to be initialized.  What I'm curious about is that in the process of loading my other views from nibs, all the initialization happens for me, but not with this one.  Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you sure your other views aren't using a `UIViewController`? Here's a quote from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/initWithFrame:) for `initWithFrame:` from `UIView`:

> If you use Interface Builder to design
>   your interface, this method is not
>   called when your view objects are
>   subsequently loaded from the nib file.
>   Objects in a nib file are
>   reconstituted and then initialized
>   using their initWithCoder: method,
>   which modifies the attributes of the
>   view to match the attributes stored in
>   the nib file. For detailed information
>   about how views are loaded from a nib
>   file, see *[Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i)*.

Answer (score 1):

when you add files in Interface Builder at runtime it calls the
 `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`    and not the initWithFrame.

Answer (score 1):

just Undo the class name (`PricingDataView`) of the view that you add  to `UIView`. In this case the `initWithFrame`: method would be called.

previously `awakeFromNib` was called in loop. As your `customView` and the `View` you are adding via `Nib` as a `subView` are of the same class type.